# How to change color of opened Bootstrap dropdown toggle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When Dropdown is opened - I want to change default color of it. I want to change border color and background using css.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKwLE.png

Here is html code:

```
<div class="row menu">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown">
      My reports
      <span class="caret my-reports-caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "Performance", performance_reports_path %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Account settings", '#' %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My css,that I tried:

```
.menu .nav-pills .dropdown .open .dropdown-toggle{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Where is problem in my selectors ?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but `dropdown-toggle` points to an `a` tag, but the dropdown content itself is outside that in the `ul.dropdown-menu` element?

Comment: yes, dropdown-toggle is only for opening dropdown menu. - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Comment: Right; look at your selector: `.menu .nav-pills .dropdown .open .dropdown-toggle` Shouldn't that be `.menu .nav-pills .dropdown .dropdown-menu`?

Comment: You don't understand my question. I will give you a screen.

Comment: No, do a http://jsfiddle.net. Where is the `.open`-classed elements? Your selector just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
#original.menu .nav-pills .dropdown .open .dropdown-toggle {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#suggested.menu .nav-pills .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mjbN7/

`.open` doesn't exist in the element chain.

And here is your fiddle with the border (which had both the `.open` and no `border-style` or `border-width` to style):

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bdCMU/4/

Comment: I want to ask you one more thins - how I can make select list look the same as this dropdowns ? Is it possible just to use nav pills in select lists?

Answer (score 37):

Use this class if you are using the latest version of Bootstrap.

```
    .dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle {
        background:#FFF !important; 
        color:#000 !important;
    }
```

It solve my problem, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, too:

```
.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background:#FFF !important;
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Best solution if you have more that one dropdown!

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-pills .open .dropdown-toggle, .nav > .open.active > a:hover {
    background-color:#222;
    border-color: #333;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
/*
* nav-pills
*/
.nav-pills 
{
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    height:32px;
}
.nav-pills > li 
{
    height:32px;
}
.nav-pills > li > a 
{
    padding-top: 6px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4e5664;
    height:32px;
}
.nav-pills > li > a:hover, 
.nav-pills > li.hover > a 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}

/*
* nav-pills dropdown 
*/
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.active.open > a, 
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.active.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.open > a, 
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.active.open > a, 
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.active.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.open > a, 
.nav.nav-pills > li.dropdown.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}

/*
* nav-pills dropdown-menu
*/
.nav-pills > li > ul.dropdown-menu 
{
    background-color: #4e5664;
}
.nav-pills > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: white;

    background-color: #4e5664;
}
.nav-pills > li > dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, 
.nav-pills > li > dropdown-menu > li.hover > a 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
.nav-pills > li  > dropdown-menu > li.active > a 
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

sample:
http://wp.rstecinfo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/nav-pills.png