# Changing the background color of the tab in navigation bar after moving away the mouse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When you click on the About tab, it will show a drop down. The elements of the dropdown have light blue background. Now, when you move your mouse away from About when the drop down is still active then the background is white. I want to change the white background to the light blue background. How can i achieve this? I appreciate your help. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Company Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #B21A09;
        z-index: 9999;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
      }

      .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
        color: #fff !important;
      }   

      .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: transparent;
        color: #fff !important;
      }  

      .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #5A79A5;
      }

      .navbar-nav li a:hover, a:visited, .navbar-nav li.active a {
        background-color: #5A79A5 !important;
      }

      .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
        background-color: #9CAAC6 !important;
      }

      a:active.dropdown-toggle {
        background-color: #5A79A5 !important;

      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ABOUT
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">D</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">E</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With how your current CSS is laid out, try to use:

CSS

```
  .open .dropdown-toggle{
        background-color: #9CAAC6 !important;
  }
```

HTML

```
 <li class="dropdown open">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
     ABOUT
     <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>     
 </li>
```

[Example from bootstrap docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#example)

[Usage of .open & .dropdown-toggle](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#example)

This question has been answered before:
@[Bimal Das](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288998/how-to-change-color-of-opened-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: this is very confusing. The selector used above says to select the element with class dropdown-toggle from the descedents of class open. but it doesnt seem the dropdown-toggle class element is a descendent of open. i also switched the order .dropdown-toggle .open and it didn't work. can you please clarify? Thanks!

Comment: I re-edited my solution. This hierarchy should make much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override using the css below:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {

 background-color: #76cded !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
    <title>Bootstrap Theme Company Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #B21A09;
        z-index: 9999;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
      }

      .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
        color: #fff !important;
      }   

      .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: transparent;
        color: #fff !important;
      }  

      .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #5A79A5;
      }

      .navbar-nav li a:hover, a:visited, .navbar-nav li.active a {
        background-color: #5A79A5 !important;
      }

      .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
        background-color: #9CAAC6 !important;
      }

      a:active.dropdown-toggle {
        background-color: #5A79A5 !important;

      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ABOUT
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">D</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">E</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw, i dont see .open class associated with any element.

Comment: @user734861, hey kindly check this updated answer if it  work

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use the anchor link state a:link which allows you to style a link that doesn't have a mouse over it. This would look something like this:

a:link{background-color: light-blue;}

However your code shows white being !important and can't be overwritten, so you should remove this styling before executing the above code.

Comment: i tired the above and it will change the background of all links. i want the background to change only when the dropdown is active for a tab and the mouse if away from the tab.