# How to change color of opened Bootstrap mobile-toggle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu, navbar

When the bar menu is opened (on mobile view), I need to change the icons color. I am using the [Foundry theme](https://themeforest.net/item/foundry-multipurpose-multiconcept-wp-theme/12468676).

This is what the menu looks closed:

[image]

When I open the menu, the icon disappears, because of the white color:

[image]

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288998/how-to-change-color-of-opened-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle) suggestions, but it didn't work for me.

This is the code for the `font awesome` `menu icon`:

```
<nav>
...
    <div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs absolute-xs">
        <i class="icon fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't look like Bootstrap's toggle for either v3.x or v4.x.  What version of Bootstrap are you using and what is the "Foundry" theme?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I linked the Foundry them

Comment: Take a look at line 1601 of `theme.css`.  That should give you a good idea of what's going on. I'd offer you a fuller answer but your question doesn't actually show you making any attempt to alter the color.

Answer (score 1):

First I would add an id on the i tag :

```
<i class="icon fa fa-bars" id="burger"></i>
```

Then I would use a function in my .js file to change the color of my burger when the users
clicks on it :

```
const burger = document.getElementById('burger');
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    burger.style.color = 'green';
});
```